# The button to copy the account in other SE sites is not correctly rendered

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The "Copy Profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts" button on the profile "Edit" page appears as in the following screenshot, with Safari 5.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.2:

[image: screenshot]

The background is only set in part of the button.

On Google Chrome 15.0.874.121, and Firefox 9 (for Mac OS X), the result is the same.

When I use the Safari's Web Inspector, this is what it reports for that button.

[image: screenshot]

What I find curious is that both the "background-position-x" and "background-position-y" properties for the button are set to 50%.

The issue is only present in *Seasoned Advice*; in other SE sites the button is rendered correctly.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

In the latter screenshot, where the style is closer enough to the one used on *Seasoned Advice*, Web Inspector shows the following styles being applied to the button. (The screenshot is also a link to the full image.)

[image: screenshot]

In this case, both the "background-position-x" and "background-position-y" properties for the button are set to "initial." Another difference I note is that in *Seasoned Advice* the background is both a transparent color, and an image, while in *Programmers* the background for the button is just an image (the color inherited from another element is overridden).

Comment: Repro'd in Chrome 16 and IE 9.

Comment: Surprised this is still happening; I guess the "next build" is 6-8 weeks away.

Comment: @Aaronut The last build has been done today, and other builds have been done in the past weeks. I don't think it is a matter of builds, but rather understanding what causes the issue, or having time to resolve it. As the issue is only present on a specific site, it doesn't take the precedence over other issues.

Comment: I'm referring to Jin's comment in the [duplicate bug report](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1279/41) saying that it was going to be fixed in the next build. Either he was mistaken or builds happen very slowly here.

Comment: @Aaronut I guess he was mistaken. As long as I can see, when I wrote my previous comment, the revision reported here on meta ended with _.79_; now it ends with _.82_. I only hope I gave the necessary information to help fixing the rendering issue.

Comment: @Aaronut As alternative, _the next build_ replaced Jeff's _6-8 weeks_ timeframe. `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next production build.