# Borken Button

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The button to copy the account in other SE sites is not correctly rendered](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/the-button-to-copy-the-account-in-other-se-sites-is-not-correctly-rendered)

Yo @Jin! I was editing my profile and came across this.

[image]

I checked IE8 and Chrome (Win and Mac) and Safari (Mac).

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.